# Adding order and a filter to data in a table in email template

Tags: apex, email, email-template, table

In my email template, I am displaying entities in a association in table, doing the following:

```
<table border="0">

<tr>
    <th>Opportunity</th><th>Digest Note</th>
</tr>
    <apex:repeat var="fact" value="{!relatedTo.DM_Interesting_Facts__r}">
    <tr>
     <td>{!fact.Interesting_Fact__c}</td>
     </tr>
</apex:repeat>  
</table>
```

I want to

1. Add order to the the table. So that the entities in the association are ordered by the value of a certain attribute?
2. Filter values in the table. I only want to display entities when another attribute has a certain value.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an email template you're out of luck with order.

If you use a visualforce page with a controller you can then get a list of your facts and order them with Apex before it's rendered.

Comment: I am in a visual force email template. Is there anyway to add order to such a table?

Comment: Try jquery plugin to see if sorting on client side works .Not a bad option .Since style sheets work should work on template as well

Comment: You would have to create a custom component for your email template and use the component controller to return an ordered list: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm